# Is there a set for which "in" always returns true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

In Python, is there a set that effectively functions as a set that contains all possible sets?

Comment: I doubt it, it doesn't even make sense mathematically. What would you use it for?

Comment: Why would you want to do that rather than simply returning `True`?

Comment: instead of `if element in set` you can do `if True`

Comment: If it's an `if`, and you always want it to execute, it shouldn't even be in an `if` in the first place. This is probably an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: For something like a test case, you could create your own mock `set` which does this, or whatever else you want.

Comment: edit: I was wrong

Comment: Reason: I want to use it as a default argument for a function so that the set membership comparison always returns true if no set is provided.

Comment: @MarquessofSalisbury could you provide some code? There is likely to be a better solution (E. g. just use `None` as a default parameter)

Comment: *"a set that contains all possible sets"* All possible sets of what?

Comment: A typical use case would be for a parameterized evaluation.  Some executions might restrict to certain values of an input, while others might want to operate on all of them. e.g. `lambda x, categories: x+2 if x in categories else x`

Answer (score 6):

You could subclass `set`:

```
class FullSet(set):
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

fullset = FullSet()
print({1, 2, 3} in fullset)
```

**output:**

```
True
```

Comment: To make it complete, it should probably also override `__and__`, `__or__`, `union`, `difference`, `intersection` etc... Almost everything really. But then again, there is probably no real use for a complete implementation of that.

Comment: @zvone Yes, but all that depends on usecase. Question only mentions `in` operator, so I decided to cover just that.